# Domínio sem o www não funciona

Tags: wordpress, htaccess

Na raiz do servidor tenho uma pasta "wp" onde tenho o WordPress instalado.
Coloquei dentro da pasta porque o site não foi feito com WordPress e sim o blog.

Ao digitar a url **"www.dominio.com/wp"** o blog abre sem problemas, porém se digitar "**dominio.com/wp**" (sem o www) não funciona.

Já tentei as soluções que encontrei no Google, por exemplo, editar o .htaccess dentro da pasta "wp" para redirecionar sempre para o "www", porém não funciona e redireciona sempre de "dominio.com/wp" para "www.dominio.com".

O **.htaccess** está da seguinte forma:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Como resolvo o problema?

**UPDATE: 21/10/2014**

Após ter acesso ao painel de controle no Godaddy, verifiquei que faltava algumas configurações DNS no Godaddy.

As configurações adicionadas foram:

- A (anfitrião): 
    @ -> apontar para o respectivo IP
    meusite -> apontar para o respectivo IP
    www.meusite -> apontar para o respectivo IP
- CName (alias)
    www -> apontar para meusite.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após ter acesso ao painel de controle no Godaddy, verifiquei que faltava algumas configurações DNS no Godaddy.

As configurações adicionadas foram:

- A (anfitrião): 
    @ -> apontar para o respectivo IP
    meusite -> apontar para o respectivo IP
    www.meusite -> apontar para o respectivo IP
- CName (alias)
    www -> apontar para meusite.com

Answer (score 5):

Essa configuração não é do `.htaccess`, e sim do virtual host. No arquivo em que você configura o seu domínio (por exemplo, `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/dominio.conf`), basta configurar o `ServerAlias`:

```
ServerName  www.dominio.com
ServerAlias dominio.com
```

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando ainda o `.htaccess`, caso não tenha acesso às configurações do *Virtual Host*, você pode ter algo assim na raiz do seu domínio:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dominio\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.dominio.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

O redirecionamento será feito, independente do "diretório" que estiver.

Comment: Mas isso implica que o projeto receba as requisições vindas do domínio sem o www, certo?

Comment: Sim, pelo que entendi, ele quer redirecionar do domínio sem o *www* para com o *www*, que também é uma boa prática para não duplicar conteúdo.

Comment: Entendi. Nesse caso estamos propondo resolver o problema dele (que é responder para ambos os domínios) e ainda redirecionar as requisições de um dos domínios para o outro. Acho a ideia válida. :)

Comment: Na raiz do site eu criei o htaccess com o código acima e ao digitar dominio.com/wp não redireciona par www.dominio.com/wp, depois removi esse e editei o htaccess dentro da pasta wp e não redireciona.

Comment: Certo, como você criou um novo, precisa de um `.htaccess` completo. Editei minha resposta. E caso tenha acesso ao *Virtual Host*, a solução do @RodrigoRigotti é mais simples.

Comment: Alterei conforme o seu exemplo e "dominio.com/wp" não redireciona para "www". Eu não tenho acesso ao Virtual Host.

Comment: Bom, isso é estranho porque tenho um domínio que funciona exatamente assim. Outro caso meu e que você pode tentar, é colocar esse código logo acima do seu, mesmo no `.htaccess` do `wp`. O meu está [assim](http://pastebin.com/P0RFDfPC).